# do all git local branches share the same working directory?

Tags: git, gitlab

The situation:

I create a new local branch off the master branch, then create and save a new file while checked out in the new branch. I then switch back to the master branch and run git status.

At this point i seem to have mixed results:

1. Sometimes the file appears as an untracked file and i can see the file 'physically' in my working directory folder.
2. Other times it's not appearing as an untracked file and i can't see it 'physically' in my working directory folder.

At the moment i'm unable to replicate number 2 although i'm positive this was happening, so i suspect i was doing something different the times when i had that situation occur. I'd like to know what is causing these mixed results?

Note: I'm running this in RStudio terminal but i don't think that is relevant for what is happening.

Comment: You've already accepted larsks' answer (which is a good one) but try thinking about it this way: Don't think about Git storing *branches*. Think about Git storing *commits* (because that's what it does). The word *branch* in Git is ambiguous, but commits are really quite solid. Commits in turn store files, but in a format that's useless for getting any work done. So what Git does is copy those files out, from the commits, to a work-area. That's your work-tree or working directory, and yes, there's only one of them. (But see `git worktree add`.)

Comment: Between the current or `HEAD` commit and the work-tree, Git inserts this funny thing Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*. The index holds every file from the current commit, in a form ready to be committed. Commits can't be changed, but the index copies of files *can* be overwritten with new files (unlike the committed copies which are frozen for all time). The `git add` command tells Git to copy a file from the work-tree into the index, compressing it down into ready-to-freeze form. When you run `git commit`, Git freezes the index copies.

Comment: The fact that a file is in the index is what makes a file *tracked*. So by definition, then, a file in the work-tree that's *not* in the index is *untracked*. Meanwhile, switching from commit C1 to (say) commit C42 means that Git must pull all the files that are in the index now, out of it, and put into the index all the files that are in C42 instead. When it does that, it also replaces all the work-tree (i.e., usable) copies of those files with the copies from C42. But untracked files can be, and are, left alone.

Comment: The ugliest cases are those where the set of files in C1 and C42 are different. What if C42 has a file that C1 doesn't, and vice versa? Git is going to have to remove one file completely from both index and work-tree, and create one file from the commit's saved snapshot. But the work-tree might have an *untracked* file with the same name as the to-be-created file.

Comment: Think of the index as "I propose these files to be in the next commit".  Note that the index contents (names of files *and* their contents) can change every time you choose a new commit. They also change when you use `git rm` to remove a file from the index. If you remove it from the index, put keep it or put it back into the work-tree, it's now untracked. And of course, `git add` can add a file that's not in the index before the `git add` runs, so that it goes from untracked to tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sometimes the file appears as an untracked file and i can see the file 'physically' in my working directory folder.

If you create a *new* file in your working directory, it is "untracked". That means git knows nothing about it, and will not manage it. Because of that, when you switch branches, the untracked file will still be there.

For example, here we have just created a file named `newfeature.c` on a branch named `newfeature`:

```
$ ls
newfeature.c  README
$ git status
On branch newfeature
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        newfeature.c

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Since it's untracked, it will still be visible when we switch to `master`:

```
$ git co master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
newfeature.c  README
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        newfeature.c

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

> Other times it's not appearing as an untracked file and i can't see it 'physically' in my working directory folder.

If you have committed a file to a branch, and then you switch to a branch in which that file does not exist, it will be removed from the working directory. It's still part of your repository and will be replaced when you switch back to the branch on which it exists.

If we return to our `newfeature` branch from the previous example and add `newfeature.c` to the repository:

```
$ git co newfeature
Switched to branch 'newfeature'
$ git add newfeature.c
$ git commit -m "this is a new feature"
[newfeature 10525e6] this is a new feature
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 newfeature.c
$ git status
On branch newfeature
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ ls
newfeature.c  README
```

And then switch to the `master` branch:

```
$ git co master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
README
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$
```

We no longer see the file because it is now part of the `newfeature` branch. Since it's part of the repository, it is managed by git.

---

There's another situation you might see.  Consider the case where you have explicitly *removed* a file in one branch, but it still exists in another. You make a change to the file (on the branch in which it exists), but then attempt to switch to another branch without committing those changes. In this case, you will get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        testfile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```